# Making a dict with two lists as value for single key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary in the form

Name, [years], [tablets]

Name being the key, and the two lists as the value for that name. I'm familiar with how to do the single list as a value, but is it possible to add a second?

Edit: Thank you to those that were helpful. I'm new to Python, I'm not used to things being so simple and straightforward.

Comment: Lols? `{Name:[[years], [tablets]]}`?

Answer (score 2):

Yep!  If you have tried it, you would see that it simply works..

```
>>> Name = 'jlee'
>>> years = [1982, 2016]
>>> tablets = ['iPad', 'ibuprofen']
>>> d = {}
>>> d[Name] = years, tablets
>>> d
{'jlee': ([1982, 2016], ['iPad', 'ibuprofen'])}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[some_name] = (l1, l2) # where l1 and l2 are lists
```

You can also initialize the dictionary right away with

```
my_dict = {some_name: (l1, l2), ...}
```